# regarding reshape a multi-dimensional tensor into [-1, n]

Tags: tensorflow

While reading a tensorflow segmentation, I am trying to figure out how does the following implementation aiming to do?

A `x` tensor is defined as follows `self.x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, None, None, n_label])`.

Later, one function tries to invoke a transformed tensor "x1", which is defined as `x1=tf.reshape(self.x, [-1, n_label])`

My understanding is that `tf.reshape(self.x, [-1,n_label])`should try to re-shape 
x tensor into a 1-D vector.

But I am kind of confusing about the x defined this way as `shape=[None, None, None, n_label]` and x1 transformed as such. What really should x1 look like and why doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`None` means we don't want to specify dimension when creating a graph, rather want to determine it in the runtime. For instance, it could be useful when you want to use different minibatch sizes during train and for the inference.

Reshape with `-1` for some dimension means just  'preserve the total size of a tensor'. For example, reshape.(x, [-1, 2]) for x of shape [3, 4, 2] would produce a new tensor of shape [12, 2].